# Automatically commit SVN folder content to the repository

Tags: jenkins, svn

I am setting up Jenkins job to automatically store jenkins configuration (content of JENKINS_HOME directory) in SVN repository.
I decided to use commandline options as it seems most straightforward, and available plugins i investigated are to be adopted or deprecated.
Is there a way to indicate svn the folder path and tell it to:

- add and commit new files that appeared in the folder since last commit
- commit updated files that have changed since last commit
- ignore files - i figure that i should manually add files i want to ignore to 
  ignore list e.g. through SVNTortoise..

I could also accept that all files that are not ignored are added and commited. So svn can overwrite all files in the repository by the version in Jenkins home directory.

Is following a good solution?

```
svn add --force path_to_jenkins_home
svn commit path_to_jenkins_home -m "message"
```

Comment: Rather good, but dirty.

Answer (score 0):

`svn add`, which handle all (AFAICR) edge-cases and add only needed things

```
svn add --force --auto-props --parents --depth infinity -q *
```